# Entity creates useless id field

Tags: json, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, entity-framework

I have a `CrudRepository` with two entities.

**Problem:** The characteristic entity always creates an additional `id` field in the database but does not select the correct `characteristic_id` field to generate `JSON`.

`machine` entity:

```
machine_id || name || description
```

`characteristic` entity:

```
characteristic_id || machine_id || name || description || type || value
```

**Question:** Why does the characteristic entity always create an id field named `id` and does not use the definded filed `characteristic_id`?

JSON:

[image]

How the entity manipulates the database layout:

[image]

`machine` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "maschine")
public class Machine {
    private int machine_id; 
    
    private String name;
    
    private String description; 
    
    private Set<Characteristic> characteristics;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "machine", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Characteristic> getCharacteristics() {
        return characteristics; 
    }
    
    public void setCharacteristics(Set<Characteristic> characteristics){
        this.characteristics = characteristics;
    }

    public Machine(){}
    
    public Machine(String name, String description){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description; 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Machine [id=" + machine_id + ", name=" + name + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getId() {
        return machine_id;
    }

    public void setId(int machine_id) {
        this.machine_id = machine_id;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

`characteristic` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "characteristic")
public class Characteristic {
    private int characteristic_id; 
    
    private String name; 
    
    private String description; 
    
    private int type; 
    
    private int value;
    
    private Machine machine; 
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="machine_id")
    public Machine getMachine(){
        return machine;
    }
    
    public void setMachine(Machine machine){
        this.machine = machine;
    }

    public Characteristic() {} 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getCharacteristic_Id() {
        return characteristic_id;
    }

    public void setCharacteristic_Id(int characteristic_id) {
        this.characteristic_id = characteristic_id;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column(name="type")
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Column(name="value")
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Characteristic [id=" + characteristic_id + ", name=" + name + ", description=" + description + ", type=" + type
                + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }
}
```

My CrudRepository to interact with the database:

```
public interface MachineRepository extends CrudRepository<Machine, Integer>{
        
}
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    private final MachineRepository machineRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    HomeController(MachineRepository machineRepository) {
        this.machineRepository = machineRepository;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/machine", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Collection<Machine> readMachines(){
        return (Collection<Machine>) machineRepository.findAll();
    }
    
}
```

This is all code I have written for the database operations..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this code

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id", nullable = false)
public int getCharacteristic_id() {
    return characteristic_id;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is correct? Changing the name of the column to "id" means that spring creates a new column named "id" and does not use the column "characteristic_id" any more. "characteristic_id" is the primary key for each characteristic in the table and each characteristic has a machine_id which is related to the machine table

Answer (score 1):

By default as you have not specified the column name in your configuration hibernate will use the name of the getter methode without "get" part as the column name in the table. Below is the configuration in your Characteristic Entity

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public int getId() {
    return characteristic_id;
}
```

As you have not specified any explicit column name for the memeber characteristic_id , hibernate by default chooses Id (removing get from the getId() method) as the column name for the member. And hence it always creates a column named Id for you characteristics_id member .

In order to force hibernate to use characteristic_id as the column name , you can use @Column annotation and provide the column name as characteristics_id
 apart from the @Id and @GeneratedValue you are using to mark the getter.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="characteristic_id")
public int getId() {
    return characteristic_id;
}
```

or you can change the name of getter and setter as below

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public int getCharacterisitc_id() {
    return characteristic_id;
}

public void setCharacterisitc_id(int characteristic_id) {
    this.characteristic_id = characteristic_id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately after modifying my code with your suggestion I just get an empty array for everthing. So the server responds an empty JSON object. Do you have an idea why that happens?

Comment: please check if the entities are getting returned from the database ...  If yes the problem would be in your code where you are trying to map the entities to json .. otherwise the problem would be in your DAO code

Comment: Can you please also post the DAO code that is fetching your concerned entities???

Comment: have you checked whether the entities are returned .. in your updated post i see that the findAll() method returns collection of Machine entites ..can you check the implementation of findAll() method .. and see how it is retrieving the machine data from db

Comment: I see the same issue in your Machine entity too .. please update the configuration for you machine_id too as done for the Characteristic Entity ..please try to insert some record in the db with the changed configuration then run a fetch .. to see if its working